# Why can't I select certain loops with Loop Select?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, selection-tools

As you can see in the attached image, I have used the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> hotkey to loop select these three loops. I know the difference between these three loops; the one that is not select-able using the loop select method was created by joining a an entirely different cube on top (don't ask why) of another and then using the join feature.  The other two were used with the Loop Cut tool.

My question is what about this situation makes this happen and can I do anything to fix it?  Can I do something to this loop to make Blender recognize it as a full loop?  This is obviously a thing that happens a lot over the course of creating a mesh, so if I'm able to "repair" or "create" a loop from an edge that is otherwise not recognized by Loop Select somehow that would be incredible.  I know I could just get rid of the geometry and just rebuild it with fresh fills but even that would likely create some issues.

Thanks for your help!

[image: Loop cut/loop select example.]

Comment: Is there a internal face where the new cube was joined to the rest of the geometry? (Change Vieport shading to wireframe and have look inside). If so delete this face.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog Nope, I've checked for any additional geometry that might be stopping it, the only difference between this loop and the others is that the others were created with Loop Cut and the top one was created by snapping the bottom of one shape to the other using merge vertices, but I've also deleted it completely and then subdivied the edges to create new verts, then filled them to create the line, same problem.